# How to check if an object is null if its 0

Tags: php

```
$view = new UserView();
var_dump(is_null($view))
echo '<br>';
var_dump($view);
```

> bool(false)
>
> object(UserView)#2 (0) { }

How is this even possible? And how I check if the object is not null?

Comment: An object cannot be `NULL` and [`NULL`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) is not an object. It is a value that denotes an uninitialized variable or a variable that has been [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). The object stored in `$view` is also not `0`. `0` is a [number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), not an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not null, it's just empty, try :

```
 $empty = (bool) count((array) $view);
```

Comment: just pointing out: `$empty`will be `false` when the array is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try the function get_object_vars https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

array get_object_vars ( object $object )
Gets the accessible non-static properties of the given object according to scope.

```
$view = new stdclass();
echo count(get_object_vars($view));
```